# Refresh specific cache only if invalidated

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

Magento ver. 1.9.0.0

I keep getting the BLOCK_HTML cache becoming invalid and this is stopping some external blocks of code from displaying until I refresh the cache.  I see that I can flush the cache in my code as follows:

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('block_html');
```

I would like to call this only if the cache is invalid, is it possible to check if the cache in invalidated?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

`Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getInvalidatedTypes()` should return a list of all invalidated types.  You could then match `block_html` against it to ensure that the ID is in the array before clearing it.

Answer (score 2):

I use Bitnami Magento Stack, for me this solution below was the best I have found.

I've tried to create a Mage_Shell_Class php file, but without success (invalid cache array were always empty when it runs, no matter what, and I really don't imagine why).

I've created a php file 'sample.php':

```
<?php

require 'app/Mage.php';

$invalid = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getInvalidatedTypes();

foreach($invalid as $i)
{
    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($i["id"]);
}
```

I've placed it on magento root folder, and to start it I use a cronjob that runs under root user.

So, to create the cronjob on the root user:

```
sudo crontab -u root -e
```

And this was my command line to run it:

```
* * * * * . /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh ; /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/sample.php >> /var/log/cron/cron.log 2>&1
```

Some parts on this line are very particular to my problem:

1. Since it just refreshes the invalidated caches I've decided to run it every minute.
2. setenv.sh is a script that helps me to set the environment when dealing with this particular bitnami stack.
3. To get the output of this script I used this last part ">> /var/log/cron/cron.log 2>&1" to output errors to a directory that I've created (/var/log/cron), and has given the correct permissions on it.

Probably you need to change the cron line command, but I think this will help you.